# Spring application doesn't appear to be persisting data

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, transactions

I'm trying to write something into my database but it's not working despite it reporting "Successfully completed request". After the success everything seems to work fine and my controller redirects me correctly.

**Debug**

```
DEBUG a.d.p.payment.PaymentServiceImpl - Requesting to persist new user'max_test@test.com'.
DEBUG a.d.p.payment.model.PaymentDAOImpl - Persisting com.app.payment.model.PaymentUser@86ceb985.
DEBUG o.s.o.j.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler - Creating new EntityManager for shared EntityManager invocation
DEBUG org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl - opened session at timestamp: 13771737739
DEBUG o.h.e.def.AbstractSaveEventListener - delaying identity-insert due to no transaction in progress
DEBUG o.s.o.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils - Closing JPA EntityManager
DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'redirectForm'
DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name 'redirectForm'; URL [/WEB-INF/jsp/redirectForm.jsp]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'payment'
DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.view.JstlView - Forwarding to resource [/WEB-INF/jsp/redirectForm.jsp] in InternalResourceView 'redirectForm'
DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
```

**appContext.xml (root context)**

```
<context:annotation-config />

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="username" value="test" />
    <property name="password" value="test" />
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <!--payment_test is the name of the schema -->
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://test1.com:3306/payment_test" /> 
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="payment" />

    <property name="persistenceUnitManager">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager" >       
            <property name="defaultDataSource" ref="dataSource" />  
        </bean>
     </property>

    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />

        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.app.payment" />
<context:annotation-config />

<!-- Auto scan the components -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" />

<tx:annotation-driven />
```

**PaymentUser**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PaymentUser")
public class PaymentUser {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    ...    
}
```

**PaymentService**

```
@Transactional("transactionManager")
@Service()
public class PaymentServiceImpl implements PaymentService {

    @Autowired
    private PaymentDAO paymentDAO;
        // ... service methods
}
```

**Payment DAO**

```
@Repository()
public class PaymentDAOImpl implements PaymentDAO {

    //@PersistenceContext(unitName="payment")
    @PersistenceContext()
    EntityManager em;
}
```

It seems like it doesn't even start a transaction. Hope thats enough info for somebody to help me. Thanks for any help.

**UPDATE**

Getting data works fine. Persisting (EntityManager `em.persist()`) and removing ( `em.remove` ) are not working. Could there be a right problem. Meaning just read rights and no write rights, but in this case there should be an error i thought.

**UPDATE 2**

Added `<aop:scoped-proxy />` to my dataSource bean, but no changes. Like my debug msg said

```
DEBUG o.h.e.def.AbstractSaveEventListener - delaying identity-insert due to no transaction in progress
```

There is no transaction, but where should my transaction start?

I also checked issues [Spring: Annotation-driven Transaction Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155991/spring-annotation-driven-transaction-manager)
but I'm not sure what to do.

New appContext

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <!-- Auto scan the components 
            <bean id="paymentDao" class="com.app.payment.model.PaymentDAOImpl" />
            <bean id="paymentService" class="com.app.payment.PaymentServiceImpl" />
    should do the same      
    -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.appn.payment" /> 

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />


    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" lazy-init="false" destroy-method="close"> 
        <aop:scoped-proxy />
        <property name="username" value="user" />
        <property name="password" value="pw" />
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://test1.com:3306/test" />
        <!--  <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
        <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1" />-->
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"> 
         <property name="entityManagerFactory" 
                    ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="payment" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitManager">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager" >       
                <property name="defaultDataSource" ref="dataSource" />  
            </bean>
         </property>

        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="true" />
                <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
                <!-- <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />  -->
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />

            </bean>
        </property>

        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.app.payment" /> 
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven />    

</beans>
```

**UPDATE 3**

Tried to flush in my PaymentDAO `em.flush()` which leads me to the error message.

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress   at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:792)
```

which is:

```
public void flush() {
        if ( !isTransactionInProgress() ) {
            throw new TransactionRequiredException( "no transaction is in progress" );
        }
        try {
            getSession().flush();
        }
        catch ( RuntimeException e ) {
            throw convert( e );
        }
    }
```

Do i need some kind of special session ? 
Also logged it in my controller

```
log.info("Is transaction active " + TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive());
```

which results to false... no sure why there is no active transaction...

**UPDATE 4**

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
@Transactional
@Repository
public class PaymentDAOImpl implements PaymentDAO {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());


    //@PersistenceContext()
    @PersistenceContext(unitName="payment")
    EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public void persist(PaymentUser user) {
        log.debug("Persisting {}.", user);
        em.persist(user);
        //em.flush();

    }

    @Override
    public void remove(PaymentUser user) {
        log.debug("Removing {}.", user);
        em.remove(user);
    }

    @Override
    public List<PaymentUser> getPaymentUsers() {
        log.debug("Fetching payment users.");
        return em.createQuery("FROM PaymentUser", PaymentUser.class).getResultList();
    }

    @Override
    public PaymentUser getPaymentUserById(String userId) {
        log.debug("Fetching payment users with id '{}'.",userId);
        return em.createQuery(
                "FROM PaymentUser WHERE userId = :userId", PaymentUser.class)
                .setParameter("userId", userId).getSingleResult();
    }

    @Override
    public void removePaymentUserById(String userId) {
        log.debug("Removing payment users with id '{}'.",userId);
        em.createQuery("DELETE FROM PaymentUser WHERE userId = :userId ", PaymentUser.class).
        setParameter("userId", userId).executeUpdate();

    }

    @Override
    public void mergePaymentUser(PaymentUser user) {
        log.debug("Merging payment user '{}'.",user);
        em.merge(user);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 5**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

     <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

        <!-- springapp servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>payment</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>payment</servlet-name>
          <url-pattern>/payment/*</url-pattern> 
          <url-pattern>/paymentExternalData</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/paymentInternalData</url-pattern> 
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Welcome files -->
    <welcome-file-list>
         <welcome-file>payment.jsp</welcome-file>
         <welcome-file>payment.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <!-- S P R I N G -->

    <!-- Add Support for Spring -->
    <!-- Default applicationContext location: /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml -->


    <!-- UTF-8 filter -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**UPDATE 6**

payment-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <!-- Auto scan the components -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.app.payment" /> 

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

appContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" lazy-init="false" destroy-method="close"> 
        <aop:scoped-proxy />
        <property name="username" value="test" />
        <property name="password" value="test" />
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://test1.com/test" />
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
        <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"> 
         <property name="entityManagerFactory" 
                    ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="payment" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitManager">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager" >       
                <property name="defaultDataSource" ref="dataSource" />  
            </bean>
         </property>

        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="true" />
                <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />

            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: where's the actual code where you do the persisting?

Comment: Show us how you get an instance of the service in the controller.

Comment: PaymentController: `@Autowired private PaymentService paymentService;`
PaymentDAO: `public void persist(PaymentUser user) {em.persist(user)}`

Comment: Just tried to get and existing PaymentUser from my database, this works perfectly fine. so only the persisting seems not to work.

Comment: Can you post the configuration used by the dispatcher servlet also? My guess is that you are duplicating beans (the services).

Comment: i put it into update 5.

Comment: It probably doesn't matter, but you have two `<tx:annotation-driven />` in your xml.

Comment: Actually I meant the payment-servlet.xml file.

Comment: not sure if it helps, but here's a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9774384/delaying-identity-insert-due-to-no-transaction-in-progress . I think it's the same case of your problem

Comment: meaing that i have to inject my dao into my service and not @Autowire it. like: `ApplicationContext springContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(servletContextEvent.getServletContext()); paymentDao = springContext.getBean(paymentDao.class);` ?!

Comment: Another few notes in your configuration. `<context:annotation-config />` is already implied by the use of `<context:component-scan />` so you can remove that. The same goes for the `PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` bean, that is automatically added when JPA is available. Final note you have a duplicate `<tx:annotation-driven />` tag in your configuration saves you another line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you don't have exact duplicate `<context:component-scan .../>` elements in both xml configurations. If you have this you are basically duplicating all your bean instances. What you initially had was all beans get loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener` and those are proxied due to the existence of `<tx:annotation-driven />`.

Now if you have the same `<context:component-scan .../>` in your payment-servlet.xml this is going to scan again for all beans creating another instance, however due to the fact that there is no `<tx:annotation-driven />` it will not be proxied and no transactions applied.

What now happens is that as soon as you need one of your `@Service` annotated beans the `DispatcherServlet` looks first in its own `ApplicationContext` to see if there is bean to satisfy its needs. If there is it is going to be used (your current case) if there isn't it will consult the parent context (the one loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener`).

What you need to do is configure the `ContextLoaderListener` to scan for everything **BUT** `@Controller` annotated beans and the `DispatcherServlet` to scan **ONLY** for `@Controller` annotated beans. This can be done by configuring the `<context:component-scan .../>` correctly.

applicationContext.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.appn.payment">
  <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
</context:component-scan>
```

payment-servlet.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.appn.payment" use-default-filters="false">
  <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
</context:component-scan>
```

This will give you transactions and only single instances of your beans. You should remove the `<tx:annotation-driven />` from the payment-servlet.xml file.

There is still an open [JIRA issue](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-6803?page=com.googlecode.jira-suite-utilities%3atransitions-summary-tabpanel) to have this included in the reference guide. Also a thread in the [Spring Community Forums](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?84265-Why-is-TransactionSynchronizationManager-not-being-activited&p=282436#post282436) explaining this.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your applicationContext.xml again, I noticed you're not assigning an entityManager with your transactionManager declaration. I'm not sure if Spring will implicitly set it, but if it doesn't it would explain why your persists are not working.

For example, change:

```
<bean id="transactionManager" 
   class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" />

to

<bean id="transactionManager" 
   class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
  <property name="entityManagerFactory" 
      ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
```

**UPDATE**

I've only configured Spring+JPA with Container-managed Entity (looks like your intention as well) - never really Application-managed.  From what I know, in Container-managed with Spring, you don't really need to configure a Persistent Unit. I'm not 100% sure if this will help but try changing how your entityManagerFactory is declared in applicationContext.xml.

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
   class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">

   <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

   <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.app.payment" />   

   <property name="persistenceProvider">
      <bean class="org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence" />
   </property>

   <property name="jpaProperties">
      <props>
         <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
         <prop key="hiberate.show_sql">true</prop>
         ... //additional props
      </props> 
   </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: thx but no change. by `...` do you mean there are more properties need? Sorry i'm kinda new to this stuff.

Comment: i didn't mean anything extra by the ... it's misleading - i'll remove it, with some additional comments.

Comment: hmm not working. but i found different solution approach. could it be that i have the wrong proxy? `<tx:annotation-driven/>` settings, should they be aspectj ?!

Answer (score 1):

When using annotation-driven transactions, you should put `@Transactional` annotation before your methods which are working with database. It could be either your DAO or Service methods. I can see that you have put `@Transactional` on top of `PaymentServiceImpl` but that is not the right place for that annotation.

Comment: The @Transactionnal annotation is sufficient at the start of the class, you don't need to put it before each method, unless you want some specific treatment like for instance readonly operations that can be processed more efficiently by certain database access frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you miss the @Transactional annotation at the start of your DAO implementation class. It would explain why you don't have any transaction opened.

If it is not enough to solve your problem, could you give us your complete DAO implementation class ?

Answer (score 0):

managed to find the problem.  [Spring Docu](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations) "@EnableTransactionManagement and  only looks for @Transactional on beans in the same application context they are defined in." Meaing in my payment-servlet.xml i had no `<tx:annotation-driven />` thats why there was no active transaction.

Comment: Which means that you are duplicating your beans. In your payment-servlet.xml you should only scan for beans with the @Controller annotation. All other beans live in the root application context (loaded by the ContextLoaderListener). What you now have is different instances of the same bean, which is not something you want. (Hence my initial request for the payment-servlet.xml to see if you indeed have this problem). See my answer for the code.

Comment: See my other answer which explains how to prevent this (with some links to further information).

Answer (score 0):

after creating transactionManager bean you should enable the transaction in Xml file,

< tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

or

< tx:annotation-driven />

if u written 2nd one then you have to use @Transaction() in your DAO class,

if any method required the transaction then before that write

@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly=false)

it tell that transaction is require and readOnly=false means you can read and write the data.