# Hibernate EntityManager.merge() does not update database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC webapp using Hibernate, and my problem is that `em.merge` doesn't respond after the call.

Here is my Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updDep", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
      @ResponseBody
      public String updDeps(@RequestBody Department department ) {
        departmentService.addDepartment(department);
        System.out.println("after merge;  in controller");
        return "Success";
    }
```

And  Department Service class with addDepartment() method:

```
@Repository
public class DepartmentServiceImpl implements  DepartmentService {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "MyPersistenceUnit")
    private EntityManager entityManager;
....
//getter/setter entityManager....
...
 @Override
    @Transactional
    public void addDepartment(Department department) {
        System.out.println(department.getName() + " merge: " + department.getId());
        getEntityManager().merge(department);
        getEntityManager().flush();
        System.out.println("after");
    }
```

So i try to explain problem:
After `addDepartment(Department department)` method is called from my Controllers `updDeps(..)` method.
I see this in my servers log:

```
SECURITY23 merge: 3
Hibernate:
    select
        department0_.id as
        department0_.name a
    from
        departments departm
    where
        department0_.id=?
Hibernate:
    update
        departments
    set
        name=?
    where
        id=?
```

And that's all! Why did
`System.out.println("after");` and `System.out.println("after merge;  in controller");` not execute? After `em.merge` was called nothing happened.

And data in MySQL table still not updated.
But if I add

```
department.setId(null);
```

before, like that

```
@Transactional
    public void addDepartment(Department department) {
        department.setId(null);
        System.out.println(department.getName() + " merge: " + department.getId());
        getEntityManager().merge(department);
        getEntityManager().flush();
        System.out.println("after");
    }
```

All works and it created new instance in db, but I want update current.
What's the problem?
**UPDATE 1**
Project Structure:
[image]

**PERSISTENCE.XML**

```
 <persistence-unit name="MyPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testbd"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="root"/>
            <!--<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files" value= "import.sql"/>-->
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

**SPRING CONFIG**

```
 <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="epam.rest" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location">
            <value>classpath:jdbc.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />

    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
         <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="MyPersistenceUnit"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="true" />
</beans>
```

**UPDATE 3**
ADD MY LOG4J log in period of em.merge() transaction, where I founded ROLLBACK log but I dont know whats the problem?:

```
08:54:28,291 DEBUG LogicalConnectionImpl:218 - Obtained JDBC connection
08:54:28,291 DEBUG JdbcTransaction:69 - initial autocommit status: true
08:54:28,292 DEBUG JdbcTransaction:71 - disabling autocommit
08:54:28,301 TRACE IdentifierValue:139 - ID unsaved-value: null
08:54:28,302 TRACE AbstractSaveEventListener:504 - Detached instance of: epam.rest.entity.Department
08:54:28,304 TRACE DefaultMergeEventListener:245 - Merging detached instance
08:54:28,310 TRACE DefaultLoadEventListener:240 - Loading entity: [epam.rest.entity.Department#16]
08:54:28,311 TRACE DefaultLoadEventListener:403 - Attempting to resolve: [epam.rest.entity.Department#16]
08:54:28,311 TRACE DefaultLoadEventListener:427 - Object not resolved in any cache: [epam.rest.entity.Department#16]
08:54:28,312 TRACE AbstractEntityPersister:3923 - Fetching entity: [epam.rest.entity.Department#16]
08:54:28,312 DEBUG Loader:2109 - Loading entity: [epam.rest.entity.Department#16]
08:54:28,312 DEBUG SQL:104 - 
    select
        department0_.id as id1_0_0_,
        department0_.name as name2_0_0_ 
    from
        departments department0_ 
    where
        department0_.id=?
08:54:28,314 TRACE JdbcCoordinatorImpl:319 - Registering statement [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4PreparedStatement@6c31a161: select department0_.id as id1_0_0_, department0_.name as name2_0_0_ from departments department0_ where department0_.id=** NOT SPECIFIED **]
08:54:28,314 TRACE JdbcCoordinatorImpl:329 - Registering last query statement [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4PreparedStatement@6c31a161: select department0_.id as id1_0_0_, department0_.name as name2_0_0_ from departments department0_ where department0_.id=** NOT SPECIFIED **]
08:54:28,320 TRACE BasicBinder:84 - binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - 16
08:54:28,320 TRACE Loader:1909 - Bound [2] parameters total
08:54:28,321 TRACE JdbcCoordinatorImpl:374 - Registering result set [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet@4e1d82e2]
08:54:28,322 TRACE Loader:937 - Processing result set
08:54:28,322 DEBUG Loader:942 - Result set row: 0
08:54:28,323 DEBUG Loader:1476 - Result row: EntityKey[epam.rest.entity.Department#16]
08:54:28,323 TRACE Loader:1652 - Initializing object from ResultSet: [epam.rest.entity.Department#16]
08:54:28,333 TRACE AbstractEntityPersister:2844 - Hydrating entity: [epam.rest.entity.Department#16]
08:54:28,334 TRACE BasicExtractor:74 - Found [REWQQ] as column [name2_0_0_]
08:54:28,337 TRACE Loader:962 - Done processing result set (1 rows)
08:54:28,338 TRACE Loader:1106 - Total objects hydrated: 1
08:54:28,338 DEBUG TwoPhaseLoad:158 - Resolving associations for [epam.rest.entity.Department#16]
08:54:28,343 DEBUG TwoPhaseLoad:277 - Done materializing entity [epam.rest.entity.Department#16]
08:54:28,344 TRACE JdbcCoordinatorImpl:358 - Releasing statement [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4PreparedStatement@6c31a161: select department0_.id as id1_0_0_, department0_.name as name2_0_0_ from departments department0_ where department0_.id=16]
08:54:28,344 TRACE JdbcCoordinatorImpl:519 - Closing result set [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet@4e1d82e2]
08:54:28,345 TRACE JdbcCoordinatorImpl:476 - Closing prepared statement [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4PreparedStatement@6c31a161: select department0_.id as id1_0_0_, department0_.name as name2_0_0_ from departments department0_ where department0_.id=16]
08:54:28,345 TRACE JdbcCoordinatorImpl:249 - Starting after statement execution processing [ON_CLOSE]
08:54:28,345 TRACE StatefulPersistenceContext:1022 - Initializing non-lazy collections
08:54:28,346 DEBUG Loader:2133 - Done entity load
08:54:28,352 TRACE UnresolvedEntityInsertActions:121 - No entity insert actions have non-nullable, transient entity dependencies.
08:54:28,353 DEBUG AbstractTransactionImpl:173 - committing
08:54:28,353 TRACE SessionImpl:403 - Automatically flushing session
08:54:28,353 TRACE AbstractFlushingEventListener:82 - Flushing session
08:54:28,355 DEBUG AbstractFlushingEventListener:144 - Processing flush-time cascades
08:54:28,358 TRACE Cascade:151 - Processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_ON_FLUSH for: epam.rest.entity.Department
08:54:28,359 TRACE Cascade:188 - Done processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_ON_FLUSH for: epam.rest.entity.Department
08:54:28,359 DEBUG AbstractFlushingEventListener:185 - Dirty checking collections
08:54:28,360 TRACE AbstractFlushingEventListener:200 - Flushing entities and processing referenced collections
08:54:28,365 TRACE AbstractEntityPersister:4097 - epam.rest.entity.Department.name is dirty
08:54:28,366 TRACE DefaultFlushEntityEventListener:642 - Found dirty properties [[epam.rest.entity.Department#16]] : [Ljava.lang.String;@3aa8208a
08:54:28,366 TRACE DefaultFlushEntityEventListener:281 - Updating entity: [epam.rest.entity.Department#16]
08:54:28,371 TRACE AbstractFlushingEventListener:242 - Processing unreferenced collections
08:54:28,371 TRACE AbstractFlushingEventListener:254 - Scheduling collection removes/(re)creates/updates
08:54:28,372 DEBUG AbstractFlushingEventListener:118 - Flushed: 0 insertions, 1 updates, 0 deletions to 1 objects
08:54:28,372 DEBUG AbstractFlushingEventListener:125 - Flushed: 0 (re)creations, 0 updates, 0 removals to 0 collections
08:54:28,373 DEBUG EntityPrinter:114 - Listing entities:
08:54:28,373 DEBUG EntityPrinter:121 - epam.rest.entity.Department{id=16, name=REWQQ112}
08:54:28,373 TRACE AbstractFlushingEventListener:327 - Executing flush
08:54:28,383 TRACE AbstractEntityPersister:3166 - Updating entity: [epam.rest.entity.Department#16]
08:54:28,384 TRACE AbstractServiceRegistryImpl:146 - Initializing service [role=org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.spi.BatchBuilder]
08:54:28,391 TRACE AbstractServiceRegistryImpl:146 - Initializing service [role=org.hibernate.service.jmx.spi.JmxService]
08:54:28,393 TRACE BatchBuilderImpl:68 - Building batch [size=1]
08:54:28,395 DEBUG SQL:104 - 
    update
        departments 
    set
        name=? 
    where
        id=?
08:54:28,397 TRACE JdbcCoordinatorImpl:319 - Registering statement [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4PreparedStatement@15f07169: update departments set name=** NOT SPECIFIED ** where id=** NOT SPECIFIED **]
08:54:28,397 TRACE AbstractEntityPersister:2780 - Dehydrating entity: [epam.rest.entity.Department#16]
08:54:28,399 TRACE BasicBinder:84 - binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - REWQQ112
08:54:28,400 TRACE BasicBinder:84 - binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - 16
08:54:28,436 TRACE JdbcCoordinatorImpl:358 - Releasing statement [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4PreparedStatement@15f07169: update departments set name='REWQQ112' where id=16]
08:54:28,437 TRACE JdbcCoordinatorImpl:476 - Closing prepared statement [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4PreparedStatement@15f07169: update departments set name='REWQQ112' where id=16]
08:54:28,437 TRACE JdbcCoordinatorImpl:249 - Starting after statement execution processing [ON_CLOSE]
08:54:28,439 TRACE JdbcCoordinatorImpl:249 - Starting after statement execution processing [ON_CLOSE]
08:54:28,440 DEBUG AbstractTransactionImpl:203 - rolling back
08:54:28,480 DEBUG JdbcTransaction:164 - rolled JDBC Connection
08:54:28,481 DEBUG JdbcTransaction:126 - re-enabling autocommit
08:54:28,482 TRACE TransactionCoordinatorImpl:136 - after transaction completion
08:54:28,486 TRACE SessionImpl:624 - after transaction completion
08:54:28,488 TRACE SessionImpl:342 - Closing session
08:54:28,489 TRACE JdbcCoordinatorImpl:171 - Closing JDBC container [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl@26d77937]
08:54:28,490 DEBUG JdbcCoordinatorImpl:173 - HHH000420: Closing un-released batch
08:54:28,490 TRACE LogicalConnectionImpl:164 - Closing logical connection
08:54:28,491 DEBUG LogicalConnectionImpl:232 - Releasing JDBC connection
08:54:28,492 TRACE DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl:233 - Returning connection to pool, pool size: 1
08:54:28,493 DEBUG LogicalConnectionImpl:250 - Released JDBC connection
08:54:28,493 TRACE LogicalConnectionImpl:176 - Logical connection closed
```

Comment: Spring will inject a threadsafe version of the EntityManager. If the merge isn't happening you don't have transactions setup properly. Make sure you have a `<tx:annotation-driven />` or `@EnableTransactionManagement` when using java config. Also make sure that you don't have duplicate instances of your beans. You probably have a `<context:component-scan />` in both your `ContextLoaderListener` and `DispatcherServlet` make sure they don't scan for the same components. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18380595/spring-application-doesnt-appear-to-be-persisting-data?rq=1

Comment: The only reason I can think that your log statements have not executed is if an Exception has been thrown. Are you sure you don't have an exception handler somewhere that's "eating" the Exception?

Comment: Could you control if the error happens in `merge` or in `flush` by adding another spy between those statements ? I do think too that an exception occurs there ...

Comment: I think that  after  flush()  cause my  system. out.println logs after em.merge() are visible in server log.  P.s. I will add my config xml files later in  my question, maybe thats  show  to you whats wrong. Thx for feedback

Comment: if you have log4j you can set the log level to ALL for Hibernate. Looks like there's a rollback happening

Comment: Thx, I'll try to add log4j in my project. After I will send you log.

Comment: I add log4j in hibernate and i saw ROLLBACK log( AbstractTransactionImpl:203 - rolling back). Why did this happen?
See full log in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure but I think that's problem with 'detached' objects.
Look at this link http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/detach

Comment: Consider summarizing what's in the link.

Comment: thx man, i understand my problem now, you were right.
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JPA/MergingDetachedEntities.htm
 +1

Comment: In my case it was because there where no active transaction

Answer (score 0):

I was using `JpaRepository<T, ID extends Serializable>` interface and Spring-Data with Hibernate, and what I had to do is I added `@Transactional` on the method where I create the object and save and flush.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. The problem was in a different place.
I had the <mvc: annotation-driven /> line entered in the servlet.xml file
I commented on the line and the problem was gone.

Answer (score -4):

Why not use entity.save(department)?

Comment: It makes sense only in Active Record pattern. Hibernate does not implement Active Record.