# Entity Not Updated in Database

Tags: database, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-entitymanager

I was trying to update entries in the package using EntityManager but its entity is not getting updated for some reason.
I was using entityManager.merge(entity) to update.

Any suggestions on how to fix or debug?

Answer (score 0):

Would have been nice to put the code here, did You try using @Transactional on the method?

also check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24922294/hibernate-entitymanager-merge-does-not-update-database) which is similar to your question.